# !unban id with spaces discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm new to this platform and desperately running in circles to unban a player on discord.
Its id has spaces, and I always run into 400 or 404 errors ...
Do you have any idea to solve my problem ?

I tested a lot of codes, and the last one I have is this :

```
if (message.content.startsWith('!unban')) {
    let args = message.content.split(/ +/g);
    let user = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[1]);
    if (!user) return message.channel.send('Please specify a user ID');
    user.unban().then(() => message.channel.send('Success'));
}
```

I am currently receiving the message 'Please specify a user ID'.

For information, I am not using the async function :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');const client = new Discord.Client();client.on('message', message => {}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Since the user is banned he's not in the guild, and you're trying to get the user from the guild members and this returns undefined so the bot keeps sending the error message.
To unban a user you need to use the [GuildMemberManager#unban](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=unban) method.

Here's an example:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith('!unban')) {
    let args = message.content.split(/ +/g);
    let user = args[1];
    if (!user) return message.channel.send('Please specify a user ID');
    message.guild.members.unban(user).then((u) => {
        message.channel.send(`Successfully unbanned ${u.tag}`);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        message.channel.send("I couldn't unban this user, please check if i have the required permissions and if the user id is correct");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, I hadn't built this into my little brain. However, can we convert a tag to an id ? Otherwise it will be difficult for the average unban user.

Comment: Just do `let user = message.mentions.users.first() || args[0]` which would try to ban the mentioned user, but if it’s undefined/null, it’ll default to the ID.

Comment: @ApprenticeofDiscord i don't understand what do you mean?

Comment: @Squiddleton he wants to unban a user not ban him

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly, you want to use a command like `!unban idBeforeSpace afterSpace`.
In that case, your code runs like this:

```js
if (message.content.startsWith('!unban')) {
    let args = message.content.split(/ +/g); //args = ["!unban", "idBeforeSpace", "afterSpace"]
    let user = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[1]); //args[1] = "idBeforeSpace"; user = null
    if (!user) return message.channel.send('Please specify a user ID');
    user.unban().then(() => message.channel.send('Success'));
}
```

but instead you wanted this:

```
args = ["!unban", "idBeforeSpace afterSpace"]
```

You `split` your arglist on every whitespace you find. Instead of splitting at every occurence of the regex, just split after the first.

Comment: The user tag is @Manu du 6'9#9521 and I am receiving 'Please specify a user ID'.

Comment: you said you wanted to unban by ID, which you did not provide here. What you provided is the server specific user tag. As @ahmed benn said, you provided the tag of a user that is not part of your server anymore (a user has to banned so you unban it). You need to unban by ID, not by tag. Also, please do not provide real world data - chage it up a little so you dont leak information like this.

Comment: Thanks you, I hadn't built this into my little brain. However, can we convert a tag to an id ? Otherwise it will be difficult for the average unban user.
The tag I mentioned is from my test account.

Comment: the problem is that the tag does not exist. Banning the user from the server deleted this information from the server. The only information you still have of the banned user is the id.